# How to use multiple environnements on firebase, for client and cloud functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently developing a mobile app using Expo, React Native, and Firebase. In my local environment, everything is working fine, but I would like to have the ability to switch between development and production environments.

The structure of my application is as follows:

```
myApp/
  /app                    // front end app
  /assets
  /components
  /functions              // firebase cloud functions
  .firebaserc
  firebaseConfig.json     // project api keys etc
  index.json
  ...
```

Based on my understanding, I believe I need to:

1. Create another app on Firebase for the production environment.
2. Create separate firebaseConfig.js files for each environment (production, testing).
3. Import the appropriate config based on the current environment.

   `const devApp = initializeApp(firebaseDevConfig, 'dev')`
4. Define the environment I want to use (production, testing).

   `NODE_ENV=development`

This part seems clear to me for the client-side, but I'm unsure about my Firebase Cloud Functions (/functions folder) as they initialize the app on their own...

What do I need to do to switch the environment for **both the client-side and the Cloud Functions**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can tell the Firebase CLI which project you want to deploy Cloud Functions to using the `firebase use` command.  See the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#project_aliases

Comment: Hi Doug and thanks for the response.

So you mean it's normal the two are independent, and I should keep the initial version for my client app, and follow the `firebase use` method for the cloud functions ?

Comment: Yes, that's the way it works. There are different ways of getting client apps and Cloud Functions deployments to point to different projects.